# приведение к двумерному массиву

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, numpy

Получаю с оборудования строку в виде (разделитель табуляция):

```
#41391Id    Vd

0   8E-05

0.0001  0.05192

0.0002  0.10384

0.0003  0.15568

0.0098  

0.0099  

0.01
```

Для последующей обработки надо строку привести в двумерный массив.

Для перевода в двумерный массив предполагаю конвертировать строку в List и через NumPy привести к требуемому виду.

```
# приводит к одномерному списку
items = [float(x) for x in list(text.split())]
```

Как дописать пропущенные значения в строку не понял.
По идее можно отследить сочетание табуляции и перевода каретки и заменить с добавлением нулей
Пробовал `text.replace(r'\t\n\r', r'\t0.0\n\r')` не меняет.

Первую строку удалить:

```
index_n = text.find('\n')
print(text[index_n:len(text)])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `Pandas` и не мучайтесь с "ручным" разбором. Всё придумано до нас:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
#41391Id    Vd

0   8E-05

0.0001  0.05192

0.0002  0.10384

0.0003  0.15568

0.0098  

0.0099  

0.01
"""

with StringIO(data) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+')
df = df.fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Вывод:

```
   #41391Id       Vd
0    0.0000  0.00008
1    0.0001  0.05192
2    0.0002  0.10384
3    0.0003  0.15568
4    0.0098  0.00000
5    0.0099  0.00000
6    0.0100  0.00000
```

Если на выходе нужен массив `Numpy`, то просто берёте из датафрейма `.values`:

```py
print(df.values)
```

Вывод:

```
[[0.0000e+00 8.0000e-05]
 [1.0000e-04 5.1920e-02]
 [2.0000e-04 1.0384e-01]
 [3.0000e-04 1.5568e-01]
 [9.8000e-03 0.0000e+00]
 [9.9000e-03 0.0000e+00]
 [1.0000e-02 0.0000e+00]]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало и так проще. 
Заругался на: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+')
Поправил разделитель на Tab sep='\t'

Comment: @Mike Да, разделитель сами смотрите, какой лучше. Тут просто табуляции не копируются из вопроса нормально, я сделал с чем у меня сработало. А может мне надо было raw string написать `sep=r'\s+'`, ну в общем сработало - и хорошо )

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не делать манипуляций с сырой строкой, а сначала разобрать ее, и уже делать манипуляции с массивами:

```
str = '' #ваша строка
lines = [x.split('\t') for x in str.split('\n')]
body = lines[1:] #отделяем заголовок
values = [([float(x[0]), 0.0] if len(x)==1 else [float(x[0]),float(x[1])]) for x in body]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: Тут плохо то, что решение заточено на конкретное количество столбцов. Будет три столбца - получение `values` нужно будет переделывать. И ещё `str` - встроенный тип питона, если хотите использовать в переменной что-то подобное, то используйте `string` лучше.